how to get enough sol in testnet using for developing?
question: how to get enough sol to use in developing?
desc: deploy program cost too much sol but get not enough sol from faucet
only can get 1~2 sol from faucet  per time

you can try out the web faucet https://faucet.solana.com/ and the solana airdrop 2 command
Check out a list of other faucets on this list https://solana.com/es/developers/guides/getstarted/solana-token-airdrop-and-faucets
IIRC, the SF testnet faucets have been empty for a while and you might need to  switch to devnet to get airdrops.
